# Self Study: Is this convergence analysis of gradient ascent correct?

Tags: convergence-divergence, maximum-likelihood, gradient-descent, hessian-matrix

I am reading [this seminal paper](https://dspace.mit.edu/bitstream/handle/1721.1/7195/AIM-1520.pdf?sequence=2) on mixture models by Jordan and Xu. Even though the paper is about mixture models, the results derived in section 5 are applicable to the convergence analysis of a general gradient ascent based maximisation.

I am unable to figure out some seemingly straightforward matrix calculations in equation 13 and following analysis.

Let $\Theta^*$ be the optimal parameters corresponding the maximum likelihood. Let $H$ be its Hessian and $\eta$ be its learning rate. The following equation can be derived by expanding the likelihood around the parameter values from the $k+1$ -th iteration as $\Theta^{k+1} = \Theta^k +  \eta \frac{\partial L(\Theta)}{\partial \Theta} \approx \Theta^k + \eta H(\Theta-\Theta^*)$ and applying Cauchy Swartz inequality:
$$
\left.\left\|\Theta^{(k+1)}-\Theta^{*}\right\| \leq \| I+\eta H\left(\Theta^{*}\right)\right)\|\|\left(\Theta^{(k)}-\Theta^{*}\right) \|  \quad \quad (1)
$$

The paper further says that $$
\left\|I+\eta H\left(\Theta^{*}\right)\right\| \leq \lambda_{M}\left[I+\eta H\left(\Theta^{*}\right)\right]=r
$$, where $\lambda_M, \lambda_m$ are the largest and smallest eigenvalues respectively.

Next the paper claims that (which I have trouble understanding) that $$
r=\max \left\{\left|1-\eta \lambda_{M}\left[-H\left(\Theta^{*}\right)\right]\right|, \quad\left|1-\eta \lambda_{m}\left[-H\left(\Theta^{*}\right)\right]\right|\right\} \quad \quad (2)
$$
Further to achieve convergence, we need $r<1$ or $$
0<\eta<2 / \lambda_{M}\left[-H\left(\Theta^{*}\right)\right] \quad \quad (3)
$$

Can you please help me derive equation 2 and equation 3.

Further, it is mentioned that the minimum possible value of $r$ is obtained when $\eta = \frac{1}{\lambda_M[H(\Theta^*)]}$ with

$$
\begin{aligned}
r_{\min } &=1-\lambda_{m}\left[H\left(\Theta^{*}\right)\right] / \lambda_{M}\left[H\left(\Theta^{*}\right)\right] \\
& \equiv 1-\kappa^{-1}\left[H\left(\Theta^{*}\right)\right]
\end{aligned}
$$

where $\kappa[H]=\lambda_{M}[H] / \lambda_{m}[H]$ is the condition number of $H$.

Assuming equation (2) and (3), I tried to derive the $\eta$ corresponding to $r_{min}$. I got $\eta = \frac{2}{\lambda_{m}[-H] + \lambda_{M}[-H]}$, which gave an $r_{min} = \frac{\kappa - 1}{\kappa + 1}$, which is clearly lower than $\frac{\kappa - 1}{\kappa}$. So, is the $r_{min}$ derived in the paper wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding equation (2) - the 2-norm of a matrix is defined as the largest singular value of a matrix. This singular value is an upper bounded by the largest eigenvalue of the matrix. Moreover,  $\lambda_{\max}(I+\eta H)$ is equal to $r$ (that is more of a linear algebra question, but the proof is not difficult).

Regarding equation (3) - if $r> 1$, then going back to eq. (1), it's easy to see that the sequence diverges (or is constant when $r=1$). Therefore $r<1$ guarantees convergence, and it is influenced by the stepsize $\eta$. The specific conditions given in eq. (3) are simply derived from an algebraic manipulation so that we get $r<1$ (again, and eigenvalue issue).

Comment: But, why does $\lambda_m$ enter equation 2 and disappear from equation 3?

Comment: @honeybadger in eq.(2) you get a relation between the eigenvalues of $I+\eta H$ and $H$. Eq.(3) gives a rule for $\eta$ that ensures $r<1$ - and since $\lambda_m\leq\lambda_M \to \frac{1}{\lambda_M}\leq\frac{1}{\lambda_m}$, therefore since $\eta$ is upper the bounded by $\frac{1}{\lambda_M}$ it is also upper bounded by $\frac{1}{\lambda_m}$ and it's redundant to refer to it separately

Comment: Hey, I added one more question to the OP as it is relevant to the original question and wanted to clear it once and for all. Can you please take a look? Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure what to tell you. I guess they don't have a mistake since it's been 25 years since the publication + 900 citations. Your calculations seem correct if all eigenvalues are strictly positive, else they can fail. Do we have a reason to believe the Hessian is PD? If the algorithm is used to solve a non-convex problem, it doesn't have to be that way

Comment: Thank you for the insights. It is mentioned in the paper (just before Equation 15) that the Hessian $H(\Theta^{*})$ is negative definite, so $-H(\Theta^{*})$ should be PD.

Comment: Nice catch. Everything you say makes sense. You got me digging in Bertsekas, D. P. - *Nonlinear programming, 3rd ed.*, and on page 72 he suggests exactly the choice of stepsize $\eta$ you did. Maybe you should try dropping an email to the authors of the article :)

Comment: Thank you for the detailed reference. I will email the authors.